# Update UI with background service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-adapter

I've declared a Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
     return null;
 }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     new Parsing().execute();
     return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    List<MyObject> myList = null;
    MyAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (downloadDataFromInternet)
            myList.add(new MyObject(par1, par2, par3, par4));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (myList.size() > 0) 
            adapter = new MyAdapter(this, myList);
    }
}
}
```

Now I would like to execute this service every 10 minutes (for example) also when activity is in background, but I want that when activity come back to foreground, listView of MyFragment uses the adapter declared in the service.
Can you please help me? I have no idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have to exactly execute the service in 10 minutes of interval .
>   You can use thread scheduler as :

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //schedule a thread
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            startservice();
        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private startService(){
    // you background service related work

    while (downloadDataFromInternet)
        myList.add(new MyObject(par1, par2, par3, par4));

    // schedule a new thread
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            startservice();
        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but about updating the UI?

Comment: For updating UI you can send a broadcast to UI(activity/Fragment) from service after service success response is received.

or you can use handler but need to check fragment /activity is running and visible.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion use database:

Once this Background task runs then update your data into database. Once you open your UI then you can read value from database and you can also update UI.

Comment: So there is no way to use adapter?

Comment: I think maybe in some other way you can use it. But the issue is if the app crashes or device restarted all these case adapter will lost. So avoid these issues database is better.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to communicate between the Service and the Activity. While service is like independent from a specific context, activity isn't.

Therefore Service cannot (should not) talk to the activity directly, especially if the activity is killed/re-created.

What you should do is develop a method of intercommunicating by using a database or `SharedPreferences`, to store your data from within the service. Then, the activity would fetch this data and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer Task to execute some task after a specific time period

1 You need to create Subclass of TimerTask

eg

```
class Mytask extends Timertask{
 @Override
public void run() {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
             //your code you want to run in UI thread
         });
     }
}
```

2 Start this task from your service

```
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                MyTask task= new MyTask(getApplicationContext());
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,1,1000*60*10); // for 10 min
```

Hope this is what you want